# Problem in update installation

Tags: 10.04, updates

I've `229 MB` of updates to be installed in my Ubuntu 10.04 and I'm facing problem in installing them. The problem is that when I try to install them a message appears on the screen saying that:

```
it requires the installation from untrusted sources
```

And update is aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and do as

```
sudo -i
```

give the password and then type as

```
apt-get update ; apt-get -u upgrade ;apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

at doing upgrade and dist-upgrade its gives you a prompt of Y/N to install the updates with the same above message , Give Yes and then all updates will be installed .

Answer (score 0):

Ahh... 10.04 was a long time ago for me. I don't know how much this will help but in the Update Manager  you wanna go to Settings -> Software Sources

Check to see if there is anything that is not supported by Canonical such as PPAs or other weird entries. They may be causing your problem. Or if you can tell what specific update is causing the problem, just don't check that update.

Or since they DO have the next LTS out open a terminal up and run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

to upgrade to 12.04. That will clean up a lot of issues, but **back up** your important stuff just in case.

I'm writing this from 12.04

Answer (score 0):

for softwares from untrusted sources you have to add their specific 'ppa's (repositories) using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:"repository url"

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```